# XCode 4 Adding Run Script Build Phase Grayed Out

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

I am trying to select "Add Run Script Build Phase" under "Editor" > "Add Build Phase" in XCode 4, but the option is grayed out. Does anyone know why this would be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

This is now different...again...in XCode 6. There's a "+" button in the top left corner of the Build Phases area that will give you the New Run Script Phase option. I'll come back after the NDA has lifted to post screenshots.

Answer (score 11):

In case this wasn't answered, the step by step on adding a run script build phase is posted at http://runscriptbuildphase.com. It has the steps for Xcode 4 and Xcode 3.

Comment: This wasn't answered. The correct answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384024/test-phase-is-grayed-out-in-xcode-4

Comment: No, that's an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 7):

Screenshot of new 'plus' icon initially mentioned by @d2burke for those who have had difficulty finding it in Xcode 6 +

[image: Screenshot of plus icon]

Answer (score 6):

Did you select your target and there the build-phases tab in the main view? then it should lighten up

hth

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Xcode too, but after googling same problem,i found that the solution is very simple. 
you should press on your target( left panel, then u click on Build phase (not build setting) ), after that you can add new build phase settings.

Answer (score 2):

I was just working on this same problem with XCode 5.  Even if you are already on the "Build Phase" tab, you need to click Build Phase, then immediately click Editor --> Add Build Phase