# Xcode 5 Product -> Test is grayed out

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xctest

My Xcode 5 Product -> Test is grayed out but I can still run my unit tests directly by clicking play from the Test Navigator.

Any idea what's causing Product -> Test to gray out?

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384024/test-phase-is-grayed-out-in-xcode-4

Comment: Still a valid question in Xcode 10.2

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's because the Scheme is incorrectly configured (for the Test action). Set the test target and check those checkboxes.

Comment: In my case, I actually have two schemes with similar configuration.  One scheme would show Test and another wouldn't.  I deleted the latter one.

Answer (score 113):

For me, the issue was that my scheme didn't have the test project listed. Go to Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme then choose Test on the left, and add the tests to this scheme.[image]

Comment: Nice! My tests used to work for me. I'm not sure what changed, but it's working again. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue. An xCode 9.4.1 close and re-open worked.

Comment: yeah, adding a user friendly alert like, "You don't have any tests configured, try editing your scheme"... just isn't Apple's style any more :(

All it does when you Command-U is "beep"... very helpful