# Adding test target to an existing project is not working

Tags: ios, xcode6.1, xctest

I need to add test cases to an existing project, so I tried adding a new test target via

1. File -> New -> Target -> Cocoa Touch Testing Bundle
2. From the test navigator filter bar.

Even after adding, the target is not getting listed in the test filter bar. 
May be because of this issue, `Product -> Test` option is diabled in my project.
Also I could see some differnce between the build setting in my project and another sample project I started in Xcode 6.1 in which `Product -> Test` option is enabled and everything working fine for Test cases.

Please find the build settings screen shots.
[image: My Project Build settings]
[image: Sample Project's Build settings]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact problem. It turns out my existing project was creating my Cocoa Touch Testing Bundle with the .app extension when it should've been a .xctest extension.

You can fix this by going to your test target you created. `Build Settings > Wrapper Extension` and changing it from `app` to `xctest`.

You may have to restart Xcode after this change to select your test target.

UPDATE: I found out the reason the Testing Bundle was becoming a `.app` extension in the first place. I had to go to the main project `Wrapper Extension` and make sure it was blank instead of `.app`. Apparently that was forcing all targets to become `.app` extension as well.

Comment: Thank you.  When I removed the main project Wrapper Extension the next test target I created did not have any extension at all so I had to manually add "xctest" in Build Settings > Wrapper Extension.